# Backslash Disappears from Filename

Tags: php, javascript, backslash, slash

This is my code:

```
<script>
document.getElementById(div').innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openPhpFile (\'asdasD\\Asdeqw.txt\');">efff</a>';
</script>
```

When the `openPhpFile` function runs, I alert the filename, and the \ characters are gone, even though they are doubled.  `addslashes()` doesn't help; what can it be?

Comment: wee need to look at the function openPhpFile and the .php file to solve your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do this instead:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  (function () { // Closures are your friend
    // Declare variables
    var theDiv, theLink;
    // Create the link and assign attributes
    theLink = document.createElement('a');
    theLink.innerHTML = 'efff';
    theLink.href = '#';
    theLink.onclick = function () {
      openPhpFile('asdasD\\Asdeqw.txt');
    };
    // Get a reference to the container, empty the container and add the link
    theDiv = document.getElementById('div');
    theDiv.innerHTML = '';
    theDiv.appendChild(theLink);
  })();
</script>
```

Remember that if you are `echo`ing the from PHP inside double quotes, you will actually need **4** backslashes. This is because PHP will also use the double backslash sequence, and would only output one. So if you want PHP to echo 2 backslashes, you need to put 4 in.

Comment: The "href" should just be "#" or something; no reason for it to be a "javascript:" bogus URL.

Comment: @DaveRandom No the right way to do it is using `addEventListener` or `attachEvent` because `onClick` is not cross browser compatible. See http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

Comment: @AmirRaminfar While I can't really argue with that, I don't know of one single (modern) browser in which it doesn't work - although I'm happy to be corrected.

Comment: All this aside, in jQuery this would be one line. :)

Comment: @AmirRaminfar It's not that bad in regular js, this is doing it in the most complex way possible

Comment: @AmirRaminfar Now that, I'll +1.

Comment: @DaveRandom, the `.onclick` is not frowned upon because it's incompatible (AFAIK) but because there can only be one listener at a time (and even that can be overcome with a mini framework). So it's completely fine here. It doesn't support selecting event capture or event bubbling though like `addEventListener` does.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
var div = document.getElementById("div");

div.innerHTML = '<a>efff</a>';

div.firstChild.onclick = function () {
  openPhpFile('asdasD\\\\Asdeqw.txt');
};
```

Comment: hmm thats ok, and if filename is in a var, I should use addslashes(addslashes()), so twice?

Comment: +1, I do like this. Will an `a` with no `href` not result in a page reload though?

Comment: @DaveRandom I haven't tested, not in google chrome at least JohnSmith, you need to add the php code so we can tell what needs to be done..

Answer (score 1):

If you open js console you will see that it gets turned in to `asdasD\Asdeqw.txt`

So try adding another slash.

```
'<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openPhpFile (\'asdasD\\\Asdeqw.txt\');">efff</a>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting 4 of them instead of 2 or 3 for each backslash?

Answer (score 1):

Just wondering why you need a backslash here? Don't All OS's support (and most even prefer) forward slash? Perhaps i have been in Linux world too long.

I would just use forward slash, at least for your double-backslash (obviously not for the quotes). I would be interested to know what you are doing that means that a forward slash wouldn't work.

Comment: you are totally right, but sadly __FILE__ uses the backslash :)

Comment: Typical JS ugliness. ... that's all i have to say.

Comment: @JohnSmith ...so just `str_replace('\\','/',__FILE__)` then - it still works on Win as well.